# Access element in struct and union

Tags: c, header-files, microcontroller

I am writing my own library (header file) for microcontroller. I want to access elements like in the example below. How can I achieve this?

**myLibrary.h:**

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct PWR_CR_tag {
    union {
        uint32_t R;
        struct {
            uint32_t VOS:1;
            uint32_t FPDS:1;
            uint32_t DBP:1;
            uint32_t PLS:3;
            uint32_t PVDE:1;
            uint32_t CSBF:1;
            uint32_t CWUF:1;
            uint32_t PDDS:1;
            uint32_t LPDS:1;
        } B;
    } PWR_CR;
};

#define PWR_CR (*(volatile struct PWR_CR_tag *) 0x40007004)
```

And then in **main.c** (which gives an **ERROR**):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <myLibrary.h>

int main() {
    PWR_CR test; // this gives ERROR expected ‘;’ before ‘test’

    test.R = // write to address 0x40007004
    test.B.VOS = // write to address 0x40007004 with offset 0xE (=0x40007012)

    return 0;
}
```

How can I achieve that `PWR_CR test;` will not fail and that I will be able to access registers like `test.R`, `test.B.VOS`, ...

So, I am tryting to achieve something like this:

```
// led struct
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_LedInitStructure;

// configure led
GPIO_LedInitStructure.GPIO_Pin = ...; 
GPIO_LedInitStructure.GPIO_Mode = ...;
GPIO_LedInitStructure.GPIO_Speed = ...; // for example GPIO_Speed_2Mhz
GPIO_LedInitStructure.GPIO_OType = ...;
GPIO_LedInitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = ...;
```

Comment: `PWR_CR` is a variable (technically, an *lvalue*) and not a type. So `PWR_CR.PLS = 3` will work, but `PWR_CR test` is incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you declared an union named `PWR_CR` and macro named `PWR_CR` this will conflict. Don't do that.
We can fix some your code, by removing struct PWR_CR_tag and declaring that as union PWR_CR_tag, thus removing PWR_CR member from PWR_CR_tag structure.
Also we can move the variable declaration to macro and use `variable.R = smth;` with your current code:

```
union PWR_CR_tag {
        uint32_t R;
        struct {
            uint32_t VOS:1;
            uint32_t FPDS:1;
            uint32_t DBP:1;
            uint32_t PLS:3;
            uint32_t PVDE:1;
            uint32_t CSBF:1;
            uint32_t CWUF:1;
            uint32_t PDDS:1;
            uint32_t LPDS:1;
        } B;
};

#define test (*(volatile union PWR_CR_tag *)0x40007004)

int main() {
    test.R = 0x00; // write to address 0x40007004
    test.B.VOS = 0x01 // write to address 0x40007004 with offset (at least) 0xE (=0x40007012)    (or offset WORD_SIZE-(at least) 0xE depending on machine endianess and padding bytes)
    return 0;
}
```

Act as if it is a global variable. However I would definitely remove the macro and declare a global const pointer variable to a volatile object to have cleaner code and notify the programmer that he is dereferencing a pointer:

```
static volatile union PWR_CR_tag * const PWR_CR = (void*)0x40007004;

int main() {
    PWR_CR->R = 0; // write to address 0x40007004
    PWR_CR->B.VOS = 1; // write to address 0x40007004 with offset 0xE (=0x40007012)
    return 0;
}
```

PS. But you mentioned `GPIO_InitTypeDef`, which is type declared in stm32 hal library. As you seem to know STM32 and hal headers, why don't you use `PWR->CR` like hal does, for example [here](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/master/targets/TARGET_STM/TARGET_STM32L0/device/stm32l0xx_ll_pwr.h#L290)? You will make way less errors, you will move your program to another stm32 line with ease and thus program way faster?

```
#include "stm32l0xx.h"
int main() {
    PWR->CR = 0x00;
    MODIFY_REG(PWR->CR, PWR_CR_VOS, 0b10);
    // or better:
    LL_PWR_SetRegulVoltageScaling(0b10);
    return 0;
}
```

Speaking of errors, I guess VOS are 2 bits not one (at least on stm32l1 and l0), if it's stm32, I think your structure needs padding bits from the beginning of the structure, hope you know the endianess of your target platform and had taken that into account, the compiler may insert any number of padding bytes between bitfields, so you can only hope it doesn't, declaring a bitfield with uint32_t type is not standard conforming, unless uint32_t is the "implementation-defined type for bitfields" on your platform and I hope you use `__attribute__((__packed__))` with gcc compiler on that structure.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your controller architecture. 
Adresses on a 16 Bit machine:

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct PWR_CR_tag {
    union {
        uint32_t R;                 //Addr. 0x40007004
        struct {
            uint32_t VOS;           //Addr. 0x40007014
            uint32_t FPDS;          //Addr. 0x40007012
            uint32_t DBP;           //Addr. 0x40007010
            uint32_t PLS;           //Addr. 0x4000700E
            uint32_t PVDE;          //Addr. 0x4000700C
            uint32_t CSBF;          //Addr. 0x4000700A
            uint32_t CWUF;          //Addr. 0x40007008
            uint32_t PDDS;          //Addr. 0x40007006
            uint32_t LPDS;          //Addr. 0x40007004
        } B;
    } PWR_CR;
};

#define PWR_CR (*(volatile struct PWR_CR_tag *) 0x40007004)
```

Comment: How do I access elements in my main.c? If I try `PWR_CR test;` it gives me the following error: `error: expected ‘;’ before ‘test’`.

Comment: If you want a bitfield  the uint32_t for every Bit is wrong!! Try to google bitfield for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with the `define` (notice, it has the same name as the variable type you are trying to declare in `main` (no wonder it does not compile) as it is expanded to:

```
//PWR_CR test;
//expanded to:
(*(volatile struct PWR_CR_tag *) 0x40007004) test;
```

But if you change the name of define, you can use it as:

```
#define PWR_test (*(volatile struct PWR_CR_tag *) 0x40007004)

//no need to declare a variable 

PWR_test.PWR_CR.R = 2;
PWR_test.PWR_CR.B.VOS = 1;
```

I hope that is what you want..

Comment: Please see the last paragraph that I added to my question. I explained what I want to achieve.